# How do I properly use Regular Grid Interpolator from scipy.interpolate?

Tags: python, scipy

I'm looking to employ an interpolation program for a project I am working on.  I am running into an issue where I get a message saying "There are 3 point arrays, but values has 1 dimensions".  I am not sure I quite understand what this message means and how to fix the problem.  Has anyone ever run into this issue? If so, how did you fix it?  Thank you for the help in advance.  Below is my current code.

```
# parsing array into different columns
TD_x_coordinates = [0.07471, 0.07244, 0.06797, 0.06144, 0.05303, 0.04302, 0.03170, 0.01941, 0.00654, -0.00654, -0.01941, -0.03170, -0.04302, -0.05303, -0.06144]
TD_y_coordinates = [0.00654, 0.01941, 0.03170, 0.04302, 0.05303, 0.06144, 0.06797, 0.07244, 0.07471, 0.07471, 0.07244, 0.06797, 0.06144, 0.05303, 0.04302]
TD_z_coordinates = [0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25]
TD_temperatures = [283.35688, 284.50166, 285.67291, 286.80615, 287.85108, 288.75182, 289.46763, 289.96409, 290.21392, 290.21254, 289.95449, 289.45986, 288.74365, 287.83610, 286.79140]

# importing RegularGridInterpolator from scipy packgage
from scipy.interpolate import RegularGridInterpolator

# creating interpolation function based on previous steps
interpolation_function = RegularGridInterpolator((TD_x_coordinates, TD_y_coordinates, TD_z_coordinates), TD_temperatures)
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `RegularGridInterpolator` from `Scipy` the values that should be given to be interpolated should be in a grid format as mentioned [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.RegularGridInterpolator.html).

Essencialy if your data points has dimensions:

```
x.shape = (m1,);
y.shape = (m2,);
z.shape = (m3,);

#Your data should be structured as:

data.shape = (m1,m2,m3)
```

Comment: This response make a little more sense to me.  I am still quite confused as to how I should reshape my temperature data to gain this desired structure.

Comment: you could look at the example from the link that I send in the answer, an observation from your data is that this interpolation wont work with z values, because your data doesn't vary in z, so the interpolation will also fail in this case. So you should look for interp2d from scipy, or give data that varies with the z axis